# Name of capturing group based off another capturing group in PCRE regex

Tags: regex, pcre, capturing-group

Suppose my plain text is

```
foo=2 bar=3 apple="hello" msg="hello world" host="stackoverflow.com"
```

I would like to capture the key-value pair, but to have the value capturing group be named after the corresponding key. For example, if I were to hardcode the regex, it would be like:

```
foo=(?<foo>\d+) bar=(?<bar>\d+) apple=(?<apple>".*?") msg=(?<msg>".*?") host=(?<host>".*?")
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wC8nF5

However, I don't want to hardcode it since I don't exactly know what the keys' name would be. So without being able to rename the capturing group, I got as close as this

```
(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>".*?"|\S+)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/hV8oZ2

I understand that a name of a capturing group can only be word characters (only special character allowed is `_`), but assuming all key names are word characters, then what is the regex to name a capturing group based off another capturing group in PCRE?

Comment: Nope, not possible. I don't think any regex variant would allow this. The next best thing you can do is to match key value pairs.

Comment: Not possible like nhahtdh said, also it's quite error prone isn't it ? I mean what if there are duplicate keys ? I think the key-value approach you have right now is good. You might use [something like this](http://regex101.com/r/uX3lH3) and if you don't want the quotes in your result you might use [this](http://regex101.com/r/fA2fQ6) but it will not support named groups.